# NetGroup Packet Filter Driver isn't installed with WinPcap on Windows Server 2008 R2 64bit

Tags: windows-server-2008, wireshark, winpcap

I'm running Windows Server 2008 R2, 64 bit on a Virtual Server. There I want to install Wireshark to capture some of my network traffic for debugging purpose.
During installation of Wireshark and WinPcap I ran into some problems.

I've installed the following packages:

- [WinPcap 4.1.3](http://www.winpcap.org/install/default.htm)
- [Wireshark 1.8.6](http://www.wireshark.org/download.html)

When I try to run Wireshark I get the message: *The NPF driver isn't running. You may have trouble capturing or listing interfaces*
After some research I tried the command `sc start npf` in a command prompt. But doing so I only get the result:

```
[SC] StartService Error 1275

Driver could'nt be loaded
```

I also had a look at *Device manager* -> *Show hidden devices* -> *Non-PnP-drivers* to look for the *NetGroup Packet Filter Driver*. But I can't find it. If I have a look at the installed programs, WinPcap was installed without any problems.

Any hints what to try next or what I'm missing?

Do I need to activate some specific features on the server? A reboot after the installation didn't help.

Comment: Have you tried rebooting ? If the WinPCap driver was already installed, you might need that reboot to get it working.

Comment: Yes I also did a reboot after I've installed the WinPcap driver and Wireshark. Didn't help.